# Carousel image slider overlapping from second image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel, angular10

I am facing issue with Carousel slider, it is overlapping image from second one. First image is loading properly. I am attaching an image for the reference:

[image: Overlapping image from second slide]

`CSS`

```
.slide {
height: 473px;
min-width: 100%;
position: relative;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="hero-slider-wrapper">
  <div
    class="slide transition-enabled"
    style="left: -100vw; background-image: url('i1.png')"
  ></div>
  <div
    class="slide transition-enabled"
    style="left: -100vw; background-image: url('i2.png')"
  ></div>
  <div
    class="slide transition-enabled"
    style="left: -100vw; background-image: url('i3.jpg')"
  ></div>
  <div
    class="slide transition-enabled"
    style="left: -100vw; background-image: url('i4.png')"
  ></div>
</div>
```

In html, `left` style property is dynamically decided. But I am not getting why images are overlapping from second slider onwards.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this my self for my website. We need to change the `min-width` to `100vw` instead of `100%`

```
.slide {
        height: 473px;
        min-width: 100vw; // this is what I changed
        position: relative;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
}
```